# Serve a javascript app with templates

Tags: javascript, web, npm, webpack, vue.js

I'd like to develop a plugin in javascript, which will be served on another website the simpliest way possible.

The idea is to display a chat popup usable by the visitor of the website but entirely scripted on my side. I don't have trouble developing it locally but I have no idea how to implement it on a client website.

Is it possible to have something this way :

On client website :

```
<script src="mydomain.com/myscript.js"></script>
<div id="myChatPopup></div>
```

With the script using the div to implement the templates.
Ideally, I'd like to use VueJS. Is there any webpack plugin to package a javascript app this way ?

Thanks.

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly, you would like to bundle vue.js with your custom scripts for deployment on third party websites?

Comment: I'd like to develop an app (with vue.js but not mandatory) and bundle it to serve it on a third party website. Sorry if I repeated what you meant. :)

Comment: Yes you can serve the js from your server or a cdn for example, you just set the src attribute to the url you want. Do you have control over the html on the client website in order to ad the script tag and the div required for script to work? You may run into issues however with client side caching so you may have to use some cache busting techniques

Comment: I have control over the html. My issue is, how do i bundle scripts and templates to be executed and applied ?

Comment: @Adrien You just write your js and set the src attribute to the location of your js on your server or am I missing something?